# How to return all records where id contains a certain sequence of some digits PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that brings back a value based on the user id. The id is `int8`. How could I make the query to return all the records that contain a certain sequence of the numbers, in other words.

the full user id presented as..

```
where up.user_id in (7401195021087888999)
```

and then where u only have a segment of the user id

```
where up.user_id Contains(74011950210878)
```

to bring back several records (hopefully). Contains is not correct, just to explain.

Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to cast the integer column to text and then use `LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE user_id::text LIKE '%74011950210878%';
```

Note that your requirement *might* imply that the `user_id` column should actually be a text column, and not numeric.